# Retrieving Parameters from and Oauth2 redirect using flask and jquery

Tags: jquery, api, flask, parameters, oauth-2.0

I am very new to using jquery and flask, and am trying to wrap my head around turning my python app into a usable web app.

I am running oauth2 authentication with the Spotify API, using flask. In very short summary, I am doing a get request with python, passing the returned url with $.ajax, which then uses this url to load the authentication page for the user to login and approve my app. Once the user has completed the process he is redirected back by Spotify to my local host with the access token passed into the url as a parameter.

This is where i cannot continue in the authorization process. How do I then get my app to retrieve the the access token from the parameter passed into the URL? I believe that the redirect from the Spotify API is acting as a GET request onto my server with the access token as a parameter, so I image there is some way for jquery or flask to listen to these get requests and retrieve the access token? Basically the user ends up on a page with the url like this "[http://127.0.0.1:5000/?code=AQAQw_gy3tGJI4M0fbVjaNkUSMX3impQKrfq4RqAKSN9nWag3jF13Qc8KyLXvi3uXxl-7v776kZ2iwKrt3iEV-mmjuf80-sL3u36FwCtD4Y1UdlT_-cWQvbwklwV1Plvi-Fm4hzkqsN9fx64NQUMkZet1L7Lt9LIrkrrSyEGzRx-Cx-5egKrDEuNTIUa_6JyyQpFQwYnb_Qi5yDHzsGn9RaDG43SL61XeXCM4UAkLEQgiGPE0diM3EgebCGMknc4RAA2&state=dfjasod8ghlkjo98h#*=*](http://127.0.0.1:5000/?code=AQAQw_gy3tGJI4M0fbVjaNkUSMX3impQKrfq4RqAKSN9nWag3jF13Qc8KyLXvi3uXxl-7v776kZ2iwKrt3iEV-mmjuf80-sL3u36FwCtD4Y1UdlT_-cWQvbwklwV1Plvi-Fm4hzkqsN9fx64NQUMkZet1L7Lt9LIrkrrSyEGzRx-Cx-5egKrDEuNTIUa_6JyyQpFQwYnb_Qi5yDHzsGn9RaDG43SL61XeXCM4UAkLEQgiGPE0diM3EgebCGMknc4RAA2&state=dfjasod8ghlkjo98h#_=_)"

I have been searching for some time, and have not found anything that explains the oauth2 process very well to use with flask and jquery.

Comment: I recommend you to use Flask-Dance for this, more information can be found over here: https://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#module-flask_dance.contrib.spotify.

Comment: Thanks I wanted to use this. But since I also need to do oauth2 for deezer which does not have a flask-dance class, I wanted to write my own authorization process.